# How to Setup 2 Redis Master Nodes Without Slave

Tags: docker, redis

I am using 2 Docker servers and I want to create Redis container to each of the servers. Both containers will accept data and replicate the update between the 2 servers. As I research, updating the slave is not possible. I see guides on how to configure redis master-slave but no guide for master-master. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Master-Master replication is not supported by default in Redis.

But you could use Dynomite, given it's [replication feature on key-value stores like Redis](https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/wiki/Replication)

Be sure to check if all the kind of operations you want to use on your Redis are supported by Dynomite, since it might not support them all.

Comment: I cannot use Dynomite because we are using Pub/Sub. Is there other alternative?